# Deadline rule date input after now

Tags: postgresql, trigger, timestamp

Hi I'm trying to find a way to ensure deadlines inputted are later than the current time and date.
Currently I'm attempting this with a rule.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE "DeadlineInput" AS
    ON INSERT TO "ComLog"
   WHERE new."Deadline" < now() DO INSTEAD  SELECT "ThrowError"('New deadline must be after current time'::bpchar) AS "ThrowError";
COMMENT ON RULE "DeadlineInput" ON "ComLog" IS 'Ensures deadline input is after the current time.';
```

I'm using a separate function to try to throw an error as when I tried to do it within the Rule it failed as the language was wrong.
The following is my function.

```
-- Function: "ThrowError"(character)

-- DROP FUNCTION "ThrowError"(character);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "ThrowError"("ErrorString" text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

    RAISE EXCEPTION '%', "ErrorString";

END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION "ThrowError"(character)
  OWNER TO reuben;
```

This always produces the error message regardless of the date and i don't know why. As a side question is there a way to make the string passed to my function contain the current time. Something like `"ThrowError"('New deadline must be after current time %' now())`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the current manual says in [Rules Versus Triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/rules-triggers.html):

> If checks for valid values are required, and in the case of an invalid
>   value an error message should be generated, it must be done by a
>   trigger.

Consider implementing the check in a trigger, not a rule. The trigger is the perfect tool for the job in your case. On the other hand, it is a known fact that rules are touchy and much harder to master.